# Kendo Grid (Java Script) : Multiple columns each column from a record from DB with inline batch Edit/Update?

Tags: kendo-grid

What I want: Columns with Weekdays in Kendo grid where each column may or may not coming from DB. Also, batch edit/Update functionality. Is this feasible somehow if so any help will be appreciated to get me started else any other suggestion, please?

In DB:

Date     | in        | out      | User ID

5/1/2017 | datetime  | datetime | int

5/3/2017 | datetime | datetime | int

5/5/2017 | datetime | datetime | int

Output:

User Name  |  5/1/2017 | 5/2/2017 | 5/3/2017 | 5/4/2017 | 5/5/2017

Where cell for [5/1/2017], [5/3/2017] and [5/5/2017] will be editable.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [define the grid column schema dynamically](http://jsfiddle.net/darrenarbell/4HTEr/) where:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var entryIndex = "entries[" + i + "]";
    columns.push({
        field: entryIndex,
        title: "Column " + i
    });
}
```

would become something like:

```
// first column for username
columns.push({ field: valuesFromDatabase.UserName });
// loop to append each available date in the list as a column
for (var i = 0; i < valuesFromDatabase.Dates; i++) {
    columns.push({
        field: i.NumberOfVisits,
        title: i.Date
    });
}
```

`valuesFromDatabase` being a list of `object`s holding your data (`Dates` containing a list of whatever content you wish to show in the associated column, in this example a number of visits).  I haven't got a chance to test this but it should get you on the right track.

A few other examples of dynamically creating columns:

[JSFiddle with editable grid](http://jsbin.com/viqaxoxi/1/edit?html,js,output)

[Example using Razor](http://www.telerik.com/forums/ie-8-bug-column-resize-handle-not-showing-on-dynamic-grid-columns#2475693)